# IIS on Virtualbox VM, web root on host machine

Tags: iis, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running an instance of Windows 2008 R2 server (IIS 7.5) on a Virtual Machine.

I have created a new website that resides on the host (//VBOX/d_drive/web). IIS seems to have problems with this, throwing 500.19 errors.

I have tried to use a UNC share.
I have given all permissions to IISUSRS, Network Service, etc.
I have tried to change the Application Pool impersonation.

Nothing solves the problem (moving to an UNC share and mapping a drive to it at least fixed another issue: IIS wouldn't even write a web.config before this)

Anyone has hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After attempting several routes, I found one and only one perfect solution:

1) Create a new windows user with administrative rights on the Virtual Machine

2) Create the same user on the host machine, with a matching password

3) On the Virtual Machine, set the Application Pool to impersonate this new user

4) On the host machine, give to the user full rights to the shared folder

I have stumbled on multiple questions about this same exact problem, both here and on ServerOverflow and ServerFault all with no answers, or solutions that only proposed to change the whole setup. I hope this will help.